# How to engage in spinal flexion when doing jefferson curls?

Tags: spine

I am trying to do jefferson curl, but everytime I try hit depth through spinal flexion, I instinctively hip hinge. I tried to make it a pure spinal motion by trying to conciously think of thrusting forward with my hips so I can get more spine bend, but it isn't helping.

How could I progress into doing this exercise correctly?

Comment: “I instinctively hip hinge” This is your body telling you something about how it’s supposed to pick stuff up.

Comment: but then how will I jefferson curl @ThomasMarkov

Comment: Is there some particular reason you want to? The risk reward profile seems pretty poor, but if we knew exactly what your goals were and why you’ve included the movement in your training, we might be able to provide more helpful advice.

Comment: Improving my mobility. Got inspired after watching [this](https://youtu.be/4nhuBzBjWzQ?si=56QK8Zj9xkpukizX&t=288)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to flex the hips in a Jefferson curl. If you did keep your hips locked in maximal extension and attempted to only flex your spine, you probably wouldn't even be able to reach your knees. The spine just doesn't have that much of a range of motion in flexion.